# Writing the text from a struct into a file via fstream

Tags: c++, struct, fstream

I want to write the contents of the 6 films of the movies_iit struct into my file fout("data.dat").

```
// array of structures
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <istream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

#define NUM_MOVIES 6
//###################################################################################################    ################
//structure
//###################################################################################################    ################
struct movies_iit{
    string title;
    int year;
} films [NUM_MOVIES];
//global variables
char title [20], y, n;
int year;
string search;
//function 1
void sort_on_title(movies_iit films[], int n)
{
//Local struct variable used to swap records
movies_iit temp;    

for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
    {
for(int i=0; i<n-1; i++)
        {
/*If s[i].title is later in alphabet than
s[i+1].title, swap the two records*/
        if(films[i].title>films[i+1].title)
            {
                temp = films[i];
                films[i] = films[i+1];
                films[i+1] = temp;
            }  
        }
    }
}
//end function 1
//function query1 prototype
void query1 (movies_iit movie);
//function query2 prototype
void query2 (movies_iit movie);
//function 2 prototype
void printmovie (movies_iit movie);
//###################################################################################################    ################
//beginning of main
//###################################################################################################    ################
int main ()
{
//login
//username: user
//password: word
string mystr;
int n;
char response;
string pass;
string name;
//output object
ofstream fout ("data.dat");
cout << "enter your username "<<endl;
cin >> name;
cout << "enter your password "<<endl;
cin >> pass;

cout << "\n" << endl;

if (name == "user" && pass == "word")
    cout << "Welcome, user." << endl;
else
{cout << "###" <<  "unrecognized username/password combination" << "\t" << "please try again"     << "###" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}

cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

cout << "\n" << endl;

for (n=0; n<NUM_MOVIES; n++)
{
    cout << "Enter title: ";
    getline (cin,films[n].title);
    cout << "Enter year: ";
    getline (cin,mystr);
    stringstream(mystr) >> films[n].year;
}
//sort records, function 1 call
sort_on_title(films, NUM_MOVIES);
cout << "\nYou have entered these movies:\n";
for (n=0; n<NUM_MOVIES; n++) 
    printmovie (films[n]);  //function 2 call
//Query 1
cout << "Perform an alphabetical search? (y/n)" << endl;
cin >> response;

if (response == 'y')
    {cout << "Please enter title" << endl;
    cin >> title;
    for (n=0; n<NUM_MOVIES; n++)
        {query1 (films[n]);
            response == n;
        }
    }
else if (response == 'n')
    cout << "\n" << endl;
else
    cout << "invalid entry" << endl;
//Query 2
cout << "Perform a chronological search? (y/n)" << endl;
cin >> response;
//greater than
if (response == 'y')
{   cout << "greater than what year?" << endl;
    cin >> year;
    for (n=0; n<NUM_MOVIES; n++)
        {   query2 (films[n]);
        }
}
else if (response == 'n')
    cout << "Thank you, goodbye." << endl;
else
    cout << "invalid entry" << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
//###################################################################################################    ################
//end of main
//###################################################################################################    ################
//function 2 definition
void printmovie (movies_iit movie)
{
  cout << movie.title;
  cout << " (" << movie.year << ")\n";
}
//function query1 defintion
void query1 (movies_iit movie)
{
  if (movie.title == title)
      {cout << " >> " << movie.title;
  cout << " (" << movie.year << ")\n";}
  else
      {cout << movie.title;
  cout << " (" << movie.year << ")\n";}
}
//function query2 definition
void query2 (movies_iit movie)
{
  if (movie.year >= year)
      {cout << movie.title;
        cout << " (" << movie.year << ")\n";
      }
}
```

This code is currently designed to recieve 6 movie names and release dates (respectively) and allow a user to query through them.  I would now like to write the contents of each of the 6 elements as a seperate line in my file.  How would I go about doing that?

Comment: This is quite basic, are you completely stuck? We normally expect people who are asking for code to show the effort they have made. So post the code you have written in trying to do this, and you'll get some help with it.

Comment: Providing code is good. Providing well formatted code is *better*!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you've already written all the code you need, you just need a slightly new arrangement of it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_MOVIES; ++i)
{
    fout << films[i].title;
    fout << " (" << films[i].year << ")\n";
}
```

BTW your sorting code doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, so it is. Appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem, I'm thinking twice about what I said about your sorting code. Oh well, if it doesn't work I'm sure you'll know.